# Create a mac and windows app that opens local html and javascript pages

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, localhost

I am having the hardest time heading this in the direction I want.

I want to create web apps that will open locally separate from a browser. The app needs to be able to access the internet for database stuff but I want the ability to be able to download and run extra javascript and html code from within the app on the user request.

What web views exist so that I can make this easy?

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like http://www.tidesdk.org/

Comment: wow you have no idea how much time I have wasted just searching for something like that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know anything else that is similar to this? I want to explore my options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like:

- [TideSDK](http://tidesdk.org/)
- [node-webkit](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296)
- [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html)

http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-apps-desktop-2013/ is a comparison of some of these and and other solutions.

Comment: @ksparakis also take a look at this new article on the subject: http://blog.mobiversal.com/5-key-questions-about-cross-platform-tools-answered-on-massive-developer-survey.html